# why won't this toggle (style.display)

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am wondering why i am getting "display is undefined" when it comes to this code right here. Here is a mock up of the part of my page that i am talking about. I have the javascript in the header and the html within a PHP echo.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function display(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
alert(e.style.display);
if (e.style.display == 'block') {
e.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
e.style.display = 'block';

}
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<?php
   if ($username && $userid) {
    echo "<a href=\"javascript: display('menuLinksAdmin');\">MenuLinks</a>
        <div id='menuLinksAdmin' style='display: none;'>
<form action='insert.php' method='post'>
    linktitle:          <input type='text' name='linktitle' />
    linkdescription:    <input type='text' name='linkdescription' />
                        <input type='submit' />
</form>
</div>";

}

else
echo 'somethin up homie';

?>
```

Comment: Please create jsfiddle.net example for your code

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pu3wQ/

Comment: its not working. i need to be able to toggle when clicking on the link

Comment: Change `href` to `href="javascript:;"` or `href="#"` and add `onclick="display('menuLinksAdmin')` as `<a>` property. Should work as you expect

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/EerUe/ If no, which browser and version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

This issue seems to be related to be scope related. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu4S9/) is wrapping the script code in a mootols onload event by default which messes up the call to the `display` function.

When selected "no wrap (head"), it works fine.

Comment: its not working for you either. when you click on the link the form is supposed to show...

Comment: jsfiddle is wrapping the script-part in a mootools-window-load-event which messes things up. When you select "no wrap (head)" in the dropdown, it works fine. Maybe the same problem for you that you defined your function in `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Where are you putting this in your page? Can you please post a reduced setup of your whole page so we can see, where the code is exactly placed? Normally, PHP should not interfere with that as the browser itself only receives the already processed HTML from the server.

Comment: This is perfectly working for me as you posted this... strange!

Answer (score 0):

You code worked for me as tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/pu3wQ/1/

```
<a id='menuLinks' href="javascript:display('menuLinksAdmin');">MenuLinks</a>
<div id='menuLinksAdmin' style='display:none;'>
<form action='insert.php' method='post'>
    linktitle: <input type='text' name='linktitle' />
    linkdescription: <input type='text' name='linkdescription' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
</div>

<script>
function display(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if (e.style.display == 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    e.style.display = 'block';

    }
}
</script>
```

I think your issue is with scoping. Try having the JS code on the head part of the HTML file and put the mark up in the body.

If you are comfortable with jQuery here is the version that works like you expect.
http://jsfiddle.net/pu3wQ/8/

Here is a much shorter version with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/pu3wQ/11/

Comment: my js code is in the header!

how come if you take that code out of the <script> and put it in the js part of jsfiddle it doesn't work?

Comment: Inside the script tag put windows.load=function(){}; and put all that JS code inside that function. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the name of the function to be more descriptive of what it does. Also, check that you get an element before trying to do something with it. And when toggling the display property, you are much better to toggle between "none" and "" (see below):

```
function toggleDisplay(id) {

  var element = document.getElementById(id);

  // Only proceed if an element was found
  if (element && element.style) {

    if (element.style.display == 'none') {
        element.style.display = '';  // empty string

    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Setting display to '' allows it to return to its default (or whatever value it might inherit or be set to by CSS), which may not be block. Also, if the property hasn't been explicitly set, it will be '' even if the computed value is 'block' (or inline-block or table or inline-table or one of the other many values).

The above can be shortened to:

```
element.style.display = element.style.display == 'none'? '' : 'none';
```

Also, don't use an A element and fake href when some other element (like a button or styled span) is better for the job. A elements have default behaviour that makes them unsuitable.

Lastly, I would change the name of the function so it's more aligned with what the function actually does, so:

```
<span id='menuLinks' onclick="toggleDisplay('menuLinksAdmin');">MenuLinks</span>
```

Then add CSS to style the span the way you want, maybe:

```
#menuLinks {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```